# Steps for integrating an HTML design to a website page and managing its content from backend

Tags: craft3, php, craft2

I am a beginner to Craft CMS. I have an HTML design for Craft integration. I need to covert this to a live URL page on my website. Also, I need to manage its content from the backend. I think we need to do something related to entries, but I don't know what part I need to do first and what to do second, etc. Can anyone please help for the steps needed for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest getting your static HTML site up and running with twig, then slowly adding dynamic elements as you learn more about Craft.

Start with two template files **_layout.twig** and **index.twig**. **_layout.twig** is the file that all pages will extend, so it will contain all your html meta, css, js, etc. Within the **_layout.twig** you can define areas that can have content injected into, so in the example below I have the 'content' block.

**_layout.twig**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      {% block content %}
         Content will go here, if no content found this message will display.
      {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

We can then extend the layout from the index.twig page by defining the content area.

**index.twig**, accessible from yourdomain.com/index (or yourdomain.com)

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1>I love puppy dogs</h1>
        <p>Puppy dogs love me</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

After that, once you have created your first section you will be able to make your pages dynamic.

**index.twig**

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        {{ entry.body }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In terms of creating sections and entries you will need to invest some time looking at the [available resources](https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-3-tutorials) then post here or jump on the discord server if you need help with specific things.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this one